# Uploading binary files using dropbox java api

Tags: java, file-upload, dropbox

Could you point me out to a code or url where I can find some examples how to use dropbox java api and upload binary files like, .doc files jpg and video files.

Current examples in the web only point to uploading a text file. But when I try to read files using java InputStream and convert them to byte array and pass into dropbox file upload functions files get corrupted. Same issue with downloading files as well. Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Waruna.

EDIT--
Code Sample

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte [] buf = new byte[1024];
for(int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
    bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
    System.out.println("read "+ readNum + "bytes,");
}

ByteArrayInputStream inputStream2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());

Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/uploads/"+file.getName(), inputStream2, file.toString().length(), null, null);
System.out.println("Done. \nRevision of file: " + newEntry.rev + " " + newEntry.mimeType);
return newEntry.rev;
```

Comment: Post your code, so we can suggest you where it is wrong!

Comment: Hi, thanks, I update the question with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument of `DropboxAPI.putFile()` should be the number of bytes to read from the input stream - You are passing the length of the filename.

Instead of

```
Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/uploads/"+file.getName(), inputStream2,
            file.toString().length(), null, null);
```

Use

```
Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/uploads/"+file.getName(), inputStream2,
            bos.size(), null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this work perfectly. I lost quite a lot of development time because of this small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to convert to byte array, simply use FileInputStream is enough for a file, txt as well as binary. The following code works, I just tested with JPG.

```
    DropboxAPI<?> client = new DropboxAPI<WebAuthSession>(session);

    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("some_pic.jpg");
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        DropboxAPI.Entry newEntry = client.putFile("/testing.jpg", inputStream,
                file.length(), null, null);
        System.out.println("The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
    } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
        // User has unlinked, ask them to link again here.
        System.out.println("User has unlinked.");
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong while uploading.");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```